# Python, Read from txt file and split data

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a programming exercise that I am working on.

So I have this text file (.txt) with lines that look something like this:

```
'X', ['X', 'a', ... , 'b'], 'There should be 5 of X in this vector'
```

And what I want is to define a function that reads this data into python line by line and send each line back as three variables, for this specific line above I want the function to send back this:

```
var = 'X'
vek = ['X', 'a', ... , 'b']
strng = 'There should be 5 of X in this vector'
```

this is how far i've got

```
def reading(file, linenumber):

    text = open(file, 'r')
    data = text.readlines()


    return something
    text.close()
```

When I have red this into python I want to use this returned data in a code that "counts how many times the variable (var) are repeated in the vector/list (vek) and then print out that number to see if it agree with the statement (strng). I think I can handle this last part, I just need some help with the reading and splitting.

Also I want to say that I am really new into python, I saw my first code for like 2 weeks ago. I have however done abit MATLAB so I am familiar with for, while, if-elif-else and I understand some basic programming. I am using 2.7 version.

Please have some patience with me :)

Comment: What's your specific problem? YOu need to know how to convert each "line" in to the three variables?  Also, can you describe what sort of data structure you want to return from this function?

Comment: I'll try to edit the question some to make it more clear. This is all very new to me, I don't really know how to use the proper terminology and my code isn't that professional, for that I apologies.

Comment: I think I have an idea about what you're trying to do, check out my answer below as I have made a revision to return the specified linenumber, as valid python objects instead of string literals.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question a bit now, maybe it helps. Will take a look at your comment and try some on my own now :)

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now what you want to do.  I think I made the right assumptions in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This line will read the entire file into a list of "lines" (string objects)

```
data = text.readlines()
```

Now, you need to use the `split(',')` method on each string to split each line on the comma delimiter

```
for line in data:
    l = line.strip().split(',')
    var, vek, strng =  l[0], l[1:-1], l[-1]
```

This will return literal strings, which is probably not hat you want, eg

```
>>> var
"'@'"
>>> vek
[" ['list element1'", " 'list element2'", "'more list elements1']"]
>>> strg
" 'A string1'"
```

Assuming you want to return the specified `linenumber` from the file, as valid python objects (e.g., `vek` should be a list, not a string that looks like a list), then this should work:

```
def reading(path, linenumber):
    with open(path, 'r') as text:
        data = text.readlines()
    if linenumber <= len(data):
        l = data[linenumber-1].strip().split(',')
        # Here i use the map function:
        var, vek, strg = map(eval, [l[0], ','.join(l[1:-1]).strip(), l[-1]])

        # You could do each on its own line, like below:
        #var = eval(l[0])
        #vek = eval(','.join(l[1:-1]).strip()) ## converts this to python list obj.
        #strg = eval(l[-1])
        return var, vek, strg
    else:
        return (None, None, None)
```

Comment: Don't use that part, use the function `reading` as I've provided it at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: oh ok! I deleted my first comment. It was a mess since the code didn't come out right, how do I comment code here ?

Comment: I made a revision to that part of the answer anyways :)  You comment code using the ` character (it is under the `~` usually).  But please avoid trying to put lots of code in a comment, if you have additional questions, prefer to revise your Q to include the additional details, as code doesn't format well (no line breaks, indents, etc.) in the comments.